# db.put() doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to remove a list item of type long from a db.ListProperty(long) list.

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        bla

    def _removeLotFromAuction(self,lot):
        auction = Auction.get_by_id(long(lot.auctionID))
        logging.info(len(auction.lots))#1
        auction.lots.remove(long(lot.lotID))
        auction.put()
        logging.info(len(auction.lots))#0
```

I then reference the same model (auction) later on in the same request call but it doesn't appear the Model.put() worked because it returns because logging.info(len(auction.lots) returns 1

Comment: I figured out if I add an additional auction.put() under the other one it works. The request finishes and the list amount is correct. I have no idea why it would make a difference.

Comment: You have to put the list, to update the list (entity) in the datastore. Else you only update the list and not the datastore.

Comment: db.ListProperty is of python type list not entity. So putting the list will not work unless I missed something.

Comment: I answered your other question if you wanted to undelete it. @zanemx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of eventual consistency (the results you see in the development server are simulated for the worst case, but you should design for that case).

The article [structuring data for strong consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) has some tips on dealing with this.

Comment: I see your point here and thank you. But I don't see how it applies to my model entity. I don't have or see a need for an ancestor query. Unless simply by using an ancestor key would enforce strong consistency.

Comment: Which is indeed the case, as that article confirms.